# How to only allow function to be ran on frontend after backend authenticates?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have a frontend in react which displays two buttons currently one for authenticating and one for display data once authenticated

frontend:

```
const auth = async () => {
    window.open("callbackApiRouteOnBackend")
}

const displayData = async () => {
// this function displays our data on frontend 
}

return (
  <>
      <button onClick={auth}>Authenticate</button> 
      <button onClick={displayData}>Display data</button>
  </>
)
```

authentication is done on the backend using oauth2 to get access token and refresh token this all works fine the only issue is right now the button can be clicked on frontend to display the data when the user isn't authenticated but it will not work as the fetch does not work as no access token. I get that I can use conditional rendering to hide the button when the user is authenticated but I cannot seem to figure out the way to determine on the frontend whether or not the user is authenticated

this is my backend to do the authentication in node js and express:

```
export const callback = async (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("placeholder for external login page");
  // then redirect to our redirect function to get access token
};

export const redirect = async (req, res) => {
  
  
  const link = "external api link to get access token"
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(link);
    // This is where it gets access token 
    // after access token is got how can i set a state to know the user is authenticated
    // and then redirect them back to frontend with the frontend also knowing if 
       the user is authenticated or not
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  res.redirect(307, "http://localhost:3000");
  

};
```

what is the best way to go about this because after the user is authenticated from backend I redirect to frontend but there is no way to tell on the backend or the frontend if the user is actually authenticated or not.

Comment: You want to find a way on your server to check if the user is authenticated by reading the cookies of the request. Then the client can just make a request to the server to understand if they are authenticated. I found this video on the topic really helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6wBYWWdyYQ

Comment: @JonathanWieben they are not authenticated with a cookie rather an access token from my extrenal API will it still be a similar procedure if this is the case

Answer (score 0):

You can send the response to the front end:

```
res.status(200).send({
    accessToken: response.access_token //Not sure what the response object looks like
});
```

From the front end set that token to localStorage or sessionStorage and check if the token is valid.
Read more: https://tasoskakour.com/blog/react-use-oauth2